# Replacement for System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode/UrlDecode ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to know if there is a replacement for `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode` and `UrlDecode`.

As I found for `Encode` it should be:   `Microsoft.Framework.WebEncoders.UrlEncoder.Default.UrlEncode`.

But I did not find `UrlDecode`. Is there one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebUtility.HtmlDecode replacement in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35437491/webutility-htmldecode-replacement-in-net-core)

Answer (score 126, accepted):

[System.Runtime.Extensions](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/0987afcd536743bf3a5cf868b3598e898f4aea53/src/System.Runtime.Extensions/ref/System.Runtime.Extensions.cs) defines both `UrlDecode` and `HtmlDecode`.

```
namespace System.Net
{
    public static partial class WebUtility
    {
        public static string HtmlDecode(string value) { return default(string); }
        public static string HtmlEncode(string value) { return default(string); }
        public static string UrlDecode(string encodedValue) { return default(string); }
        public static byte[] UrlDecodeToBytes(byte[] encodedValue, int offset, int count) { return default(byte[]); }
        public static string UrlEncode(string value) { return default(string); }
        public static byte[] UrlEncodeToBytes(byte[] value, int offset, int count) { return default(byte[]); }
    }
}
```

## Update

While `System.Runtime.Extensions` defines the extension, as you can notice from it's code the actual class you need to call is `System.Net.WebUtility`

**Option 1**: **System.Net.WebUtility**

- [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility?view=netstandard-2.0)
- [Source Code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Runtime.Extensions/src/System/Net/WebUtility.cs)

Currently there are no publicly made plans to include `Decode` in `Microsoft.Framework.WebEncoders`.

**Usage**

```
System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(myString)
System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(myString)
```

**Option 2**: **System.Text.Encodings.Web.UrlEncoder**

- [Source Code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Text.Encodings.Web/src/System/Text/Encodings/Web/UrlEncoder.cs)

This is registered in the asp.net core service container and is injectable into your controllers etc.

Comment: Many thanks about your answer. I had other problems to solve so i get to testing only yesterday.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. It's working, but I have small problem with it. I'am trying to encode one value and I'am comparing result with my previous application in .NET 4.5. The result is a bit different. In old asp.net i had the encoded value result this: **kA5viZqq23%2f4LCe4IboZ7Q%3d%3d** and with the new UrlEncode the reuslt is this: **kA5viZqq23%2F4LCe4IboZ7Q%3D%3D** The difference is that few letters are capital. Because of this, some values like **%3D** is in my old version a equal sign and in new version its only written as is so **%3D** is written. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: That's interesting. I would encourage you to create an issue in GitHub.

Comment: So the call is System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(stringToDecode) for example. I added this comment because I was first confuse to add the System.Runtime.Extensions which is not the case, maybe it can help to someone else.