# WebUtility.HtmlDecode replacement in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to decode HTML characters in .NET Core (MVC6). It looks like .NET Core doesn't have WebUtility.HtmlDecode function which everybody used for that purpose before. Is there a replacement exist in .NET Core?

Comment: Take a look: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/73z22y6h%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: @duDE, he is asking .NET Core rather than .NET 4.

Comment: Take a look at my answer. it is replacement of webutility.htmldecode in .net core as httputility.HtmlDecode .

Comment: WARNING: When searching and replacing be careful not to confuse `HtmlEncode` and `UrlEncode` especially if you're changing many at once. One is for HTML tags and the other for URLs. I almost made that silly mistake when searching and replacing!

Answer (score 141):

This is in the [System.Net.WebUtility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility?view=netstandard-1.0) class (Since .NET Standard 1.0) :

```
//
// Summary:
//     Provides methods for encoding and decoding URLs when processing Web requests.
public static class WebUtility
{
    public static string HtmlDecode(string value);
    public static string HtmlEncode(string value);
    public static string UrlDecode(string encodedValue);
    public static byte[] UrlDecodeToBytes(byte[] encodedValue, int offset, int count);
    public static string UrlEncode(string value);
    public static byte[] UrlEncodeToBytes(byte[] value, int offset, int count);
}
```

Comment: nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebUtilities/

Comment: For .NET Core 1.1 use https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities

Comment: For .NET Core 2.1 see Gerardo's response below, no need to install another nuget package.

Answer (score 48):

This is in Net Core 2.0

```
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
```

and call it:

```
$"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(link)}'>clicking here</a>.");
```

**UPDATE**:
Also in .Net Core 2.1:

```
using System.Web;

HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code)
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(code)
```

**UPDATE**:
Also works from .NET Core 3.1 up to .NET 5 and .NET 6.

Comment: There are also HttpUtility.HtmlEncode and HttpUtility.HtmlDecode methods.

Comment: @xhafan Since ASP.NET 4.0 in 2010 those methods just call `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode` (either directly, in 4.0, or via `HttpEncoder` in 4.5).

Answer (score 26):

I've found the HtmlDecode function  in the WebUtility library to work.

```
System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string)
```

Answer (score 5):

You need add reference `System.Net.WebUtility`.

- It's already included in .Net Core 2 (`Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`)
- Or you can install from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebUtilities/) - preview version for .Net Core 1.

So example, your code will be look like the below

```
public static string HtmlDecode(this string value)
{
     value = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(value);
     return value;
}
```

Comment: Or just call `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` there's no reason to wrap it in an extension method...

Answer (score 4):

```
namespace System.Web
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Provides methods for encoding and decoding URLs when processing Web requests.
    //     This class cannot be inherited.
    public sealed class HttpUtility
    {
        public HttpUtility();
        public static string HtmlAttributeEncode(string s);
        public static void HtmlAttributeEncode(string s, TextWriter output); 
        public static string HtmlDecode(string s);
        public static void HtmlDecode(string s, TextWriter output);
        public static string HtmlEncode(string s);
        public static string HtmlEncode(object value);
        public static void HtmlEncode(string s, TextWriter output);
        public static string JavaScriptStringEncode(string value);
        public static string JavaScriptStringEncode(string value, bool addDoubleQuotes);
        public static NameValueCollection ParseQueryString(string query);
        public static NameValueCollection ParseQueryString(string query, Encoding encoding);
        public static string UrlDecode(string str, Encoding e);
        public static string UrlDecode(byte[] bytes, int offset, int count, Encoding e);
        public static string UrlDecode(string str);
        public static string UrlDecode(byte[] bytes, Encoding e);
        public static byte[] UrlDecodeToBytes(byte[] bytes, int offset, int count);
        public static byte[] UrlDecodeToBytes(string str, Encoding e);
        public static byte[] UrlDecodeToBytes(byte[] bytes);
        public static byte[] UrlDecodeToBytes(string str);
        public static string UrlEncode(string str);
        public static string UrlEncode(string str, Encoding e);
        public static string UrlEncode(byte[] bytes);
        public static string UrlEncode(byte[] bytes, int offset, int count);
        public static byte[] UrlEncodeToBytes(string str);
        public static byte[] UrlEncodeToBytes(byte[] bytes);
        public static byte[] UrlEncodeToBytes(string str, Encoding e);
        public static byte[] UrlEncodeToBytes(byte[] bytes, int offset, int count);
        [Obsolete("This method produces non-standards-compliant output and has interoperability issues. The preferred alternative is UrlEncode(String).")]
        public static string UrlEncodeUnicode(string str);
        [Obsolete("This method produces non-standards-compliant output and has interoperability issues. The preferred alternative is UrlEncodeToBytes(String).")]
        public static byte[] UrlEncodeUnicodeToBytes(string str);
        public static string UrlPathEncode(string str);
    }
}
```

You can use `HttpUtility`  class in `.net core` for decoding or encoding.

hope it will work.

Comment: This answer only applies to .NET Framework, .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5 (and later), other versions of .NET (such as .NET Core 1.x and 2.x) did not have `System.Web.HttpUtility`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 2):

`HtmlDecode` and most of the `*Decode` methods were not ported to CoreFx. Only the `*Encode` methods are available.

Here's what's available today: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/1dfe38aeb2811fbbd6d4de36d210f060e80d50a6/src/System.Text.Encodings.Web/src/System/Text/Encodings/Web/HtmlEncoder.cs

Comment: This answer is from 2016 and is no-longer applicable to .NET Core 3.1 or later.