# URL Encode and Decode in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, urlencode

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode
```

This does only work in .NET Framework. How can I encode or decode URI arguments in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: There is no HttpContext in ASP.NET Core - or any non-Web project. The same method is available through the methods of the Uri class, eg [Uri.EscapeDataString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring(v=vs.110).aspx), [Uri.EscapeUriString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos WRONG - There is no `HttpContext.Current` but `HttpContext` is a part of .Net Core - `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext`. Remember this

Comment: Remember to read the entire comment. The HttpContext you mention is *VERY* different from the HttpContext of previous versions. It's *far more common* to use the Uri methods

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebUtility.HtmlDecode replacement in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35437491/webutility-htmldecode-replacement-in-net-core)

Answer (score 311, accepted):

- For ASP.NET Core 2.0+ just add `System.Net` namespace - `WebUtility` class is shipped as part of `System.Runtime.Extensions` nuget package, that is referenced by default in ASP.NET Core project.
- For the previous version add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities` nuget package.

Then the `WebUtility` class will be available for you:

```
public static class WebUtility
{
    public static string UrlDecode(string encodedValue);
    public static string UrlEncode(string value);
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me against SDK 2.0.0+, however Manuel Alves answer (System.Net.WebUility) did.

Comment: The usage is :                                                                                                               
         var decodedUrl = WebUtility.UrlDecode(encodedUrl);

Answer (score 110):

For ASP.Net Core 2.0+ and if you need spaces to be encoded as `%20`

as opposed to `+`;

Use:

```
 Uri.EscapeDataString(someString);
```

Comment: As easy as it gets

Answer (score 100):

It's available on [version 2.0.0 of the .Net Core SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core), in `System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode` ([see documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility?view=netstandard-2.0))

Comment: For Net Core 2+, when I use `System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode`: spaces are encoded with a `+`.  I used `Uri.EscapeDataString` to encode with `%20`.

Answer (score 16):

Just adding another approach to the mix:

```cs
UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(url);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodings.web.urlencoder?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 7):

I'm using a **redirect**, and UrlEncode did not work for me because it encodes the entire url. I solved this by instead using UriHelper.Encode, shown below.

[UriHelper.Encode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.extensions.urihelper.encode?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

```
// generate url string...
return Redirect(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.UriHelper.Encode(new System.Uri(url)));
```

Answer (score 2):

[RFC3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) defines which characters are reserved and unreserved.

Reserved characters:

```
! # $ & ‘ ( ) * + , / : ; = ? @ [ ]
```

Unreserved characters:

```
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 – _ . ~
```

We encode reserved characters in a URL and .NET provides a few ways of encoding and decoding.

### Using the HttpUtility Class

```
var url = @"http://example.com/resource?foo=bar with space#fragment";

var httpUtilityEncoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url);
Console.WriteLine(httpUtilityEncoded);
//http%3a%2f%2fexample.com%2fresource%3ffoo%3dbar+with+space%23fragment

var httpUtilityDecoded = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(httpUtilityEncoded);
Console.WriteLine(httpUtilityDecoded);
//http://example.com/resource?foo=bar with space#fragment
```

### Using the WebUtility Class

```
var url = @"http://example.com/resource?foo=bar with space#fragment";

var webUtilityEncoded = WebUtility.UrlEncode(url);
Console.WriteLine(webUtilityEncoded);
//http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fresource%3Ffoo%3Dbar+with+space%23fragment

var webUtilityDecoded = WebUtility.UrlDecode(webUtilityEncoded);
Console.WriteLine(webUtilityDecoded);
//http://example.com/resource?foo=bar with space#fragment
```

If we are not within a web application, consider using the WebUtility class [as documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urlencode?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-7.0).

### Using the Uri Class

```
var url = @"http://example.com/resource?foo=bar with space#fragment";

var uriEncoded = Uri.EscapeDataString(url);
Console.WriteLine(uriEncoded);
//http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fresource%3Ffoo%3Dbar%20with%20space%23fragment

var uriDecoded = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uriEncoded);
Console.WriteLine(uriDecoded);
//http://example.com/resource?foo=bar with space#fragment
```

### Considerations

Take note that `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` produces lowercase encoding of reserved characters, whilst `WebUtility.UrlEncode()` and `Uri.EscapeDataString()` both output uppercase.

Also `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` and `WebUtility.UrlEncode()` both encode a space character to ‘+‘, whereas `Uri.EscapeDataString()` encodes a space as ‘%20‘ instead.

There is a limit of 32766 characters for `Uri.EscapeDataString()` such that if we try and encode more characters than that limit, it will throw a [UriFormatException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uriformatexception?view=net-8.0). Therefore, if we do need to encode a particularly long URL, we’ll probably want to use either `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` or `WebUtility.UrlEncode()` instead.

The particular implementation you choose will depend upon your specific requirements.

Answer (score -7):

Don't waste your time, I've got plenty of experience with these so called url encoders, they are all useless, and have different quirks. Eg WebUtility.UrlEncode doesn't take care of "+" sign.

If you want to encode URL parameters, employ a BASE58 encoding. It uses only alphabet letters + numbers, thus you don't need to url encode.

Comment: Can you explain all these quirks, I'm only familiar with + that QueryHelpers.AddQueryString or Uri.EscapeDataString doesn't do.

Comment: I've just tried out `WebUtility.UrlEncode` and it wonderfully converted a plus sign ("+") into a "%2B". I'm using .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: @Michael Uri.EscapeDataString does convert "+" to %2B with .NET 6

Comment: @Blogrammer True, think I meant Uri.EscapeUriString.

Comment: Here's a website covering the different output from the various methods https://secretgeek.net/uri_enconding I suggest sticking with Uri.EscapeDataString or UrlEncoder.Encode.

Comment: This is actually true. I'm using a program that uses WebUtility.UrlEncode and it broke the URL.