# Cannot use Vietnamese / signed & space characters in URL parameters in Blazor

Tags: .net, blazor, asp.net-core-3.0, blazor-server-side

I use blazor with .net core 3.0 to develop a website that allow to pass some parameters in URL.

The problem is whenever I pass a Vietnamese keyword in the URL, the blazor throw an inner exception that appears on Browser console.

**Please be aware of that** I cannot use `Encode URL` to extract that information since the blazor throw exceptions by it-self before `OnAfterRenderAsync` calling

**Work**

```
https://localhost:44316/?keyword=tieng viet
https://localhost:44316/?keyword=tieng%20viet
```

**Not Work**

```
https://localhost:44316/?keyword=tiếng việt
https://localhost:44316/?keyword=tiếng%20việt
https://localhost:44316/?keyword=ti%E1%BA%BFng%20vi%E1%BB%87t
```

**How to reproduce:**

- Just create a completely new blazor project with .net core 3.0.
- Then start the project and try with these urls.

**=> Since I don't add any extra code here, the blazor should not throw any exceptions**

**Here is the exception:**
[image: Here is the exception]

Thanks for help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL Encode and Decode in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44920875/url-encode-and-decode-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: @mjwills I don't think so since the blazor should handle perfectly by default for any parameters come. We can decode the parameter values later it's okay. The problem is the blazor throws exceptions by itsself

Comment: Step 1, blazor should not throw exceptions, step 2 we can decode parameters and get what we need.

Comment: Does it work if you use my suggested URL?

Comment: @mjwills no, it doesn't. Also throw exceptions

Comment: It is thrown in visual studio. It is shown in in browser console as the attachment I put saying "The uris provided are invalid"

Comment: Does https://localhost:44316/?keyword=ti%E1%BA%BFng+vi%E1%BB%87t work?

Comment: @mjwills sorry guy, your suggestion is work fine. I did check wrong way. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe I did check with percent encoding, not + one

Comment: To be fair, %20 **should** work. Its perfectly legitimate.

Comment: Yeah, it's weird. I use QueryHelpers.AddQueryString to generate the URL. It gives me %20 ones, not +. So, from now one, I have to encode and decode every time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have to encode and decode every time

Not sure whether it is a bug. However, you don't have to encode and decode every time. As a walkaround, we can create a quick and dirty fix so that the `space` within the querystring is converted to `+`.

Since this error happens when invoking remote signalR [`ComponentHub::StartCircuit()`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/4a7bf75e89e3dfe7264a641ed041f50788d28d20/src/Components/Server/src/ComponentHub.cs#L77) method, we can replace the location before it is passed to siganlR. Based on [@mjwills's above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34092/mjwills) that suggests `localhost:44316/?keyword=ti%E1%BA%BFng+vi%E1%BB%87t`, you can add a `script` in your `_Host.cshtml` as below:

```html
<script>
    !function(){
        var raw = new URL(window.location.href);
        raw.search = raw.search.replace("%20","+");    // replace the `%20` with "+"
        window.history.replaceState('', document.title, raw);
    }();
</script>
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

By this way, your server side code doesn't have to care about the encoding.

Comment: Your idea works bro. I did the navigation in OnInitializedAsync if the URL contains %20, however it just works for ServerPrerendered, not others

Answer (score 1):

First things first: This is nothing Blazor specific

You are simply using an URI which is not valid. Each character used in an URI must have a corresponding characters via US-ASCII table.

Blazor is just calling `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString` which  returns false for your given example.

As others have pointed out the solution is to encode the url. This has to be done **before** that URL is used to navigate to a blazor page.

Comment: I thought the same, but tried the OP's repro steps and discovered that while https://localhost:44316/?keyword=ti%E1%BA%BFng+vi%E1%BB%87t worked, https://localhost:44316/?keyword=ti%E1%BA%BFng%20vi%E1%BB%87t didn't (and the latter definitely **is** a valid URL)

Comment: I believe your statement that it is caused by`Uri.IsWellFormedUriString`. What confused me is when pasting `https://localhost:44316/?keyword=tiếng việt` to chrome,  it will be encoded to `keyword=tiếng%20việt` instead of `keyword=tiếng+việt`.  According to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20) , it seems that the `%20` should be considered as a valid URL ?

Comment: @mjwills sorry everyone. After reading your comments again. I have tried. It works!

Comment: So, basically, as you mentioned, I don't understand why "space character" is converted to "%20", not "+"