# How to replace "%2B" with "+" when calling RedirectToAction()

Tags: asp.net-core, redirect, urlencode, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm using the `RedirectToAction()` method in an ASP.NET Core 2.1 controller called `CatalogController`:

```cs
return RedirectToAction("search", new { search_string = "example+string" });
```

This redirects to a URL:

```
catalog/search/?search_string=example%2Bstring
```

How do I replace the `%2B` encoding with a `+` instead?

The URL should instead look like:

```
catalog/search/?search_string=example+string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RedirectToAction()` method assumes that any values passed via the `RouteValues` parameter are *not* encoded; the `RedirectToAction()` method will take care of the URL encoding on your behalf. As such, when you enter a `+`, it's treating it as a literal `+` symbol, not an encoded space.

`%2B` is the correct encoding for a literal `+` symbol. If you want a space to be encoded in the URL, then you should enter a space in your `RouteValues` dictionary (e.g., `search_string = "example string"`). This will encode the space as a `%20`.

> *Note:* A `%20` is the equivalent of a `+` in an encoded URL, so I'm assuming that will satisfy your requirements.

If your `search_string` value is coming from a URL encoded source, you will need to first *decode* it using e.g. [`WebUtility.UrlDecode()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44921258/3025856). That said, if you're retrieving your `search_string` value from an action parameter or binding model, this decoding should already be done for you.

If, for some reason, you *want* to treat literal `+` symbols as spaces, you'll need to explicitly perform that replace on your source value (e.g., `search_string.Replace("+", " ")`).

Comment: Jeremy, thanks for the answer.
But I searched for a solution with "+" inside URL to replace as space because I generate the string by myself.
So in the next position, I saw an example at StackOverflow URL string exchange space to "-". 
It completely resolves my question. Bye!