# Accepting special characters as input from the URL in C#

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

- Language used: C#
- Input: An abbreviation or an emoticon.
- Output: Translation of the abbreviation or emoticon
- Code:

  public class EmoticonController : ApiController
  {
  // GET: api/emoticon/abbreviation/shortform
  [HttpGet]
  [Route("api/emoticon/abbreviation/{shortform}")]

  ```
   public string Abbreviation(string ShortForm)
  {
       string outputMessage;

       // Switch case that assigns the outputMessage the translation to the abbreviation entered by the user 
       switch (ShortForm)
       {

           case "TY":
               outputMessage = "Thank you";
               break;

           case "(~.~)":
               outputMessage = "sleepy";
               break;

           default:
               outputMessage = "Invalid Input";
               break;
       }

       return outputMessage;
   }
  ```

}

I run the above code in Visual studio and enter the URL as

**localhost/api/emoticon/abbreviation/(~.~)**

and I get the following error:
[C# URL Special characters error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f6vv.png)

PS: The screenshot URL does differ from the code and that I have mentioned. Please ignore that. I fixed it but the error still persisted.

Comment: In the screenshot the requested url is different

Comment: Allowed characters in URIs are limited. If you need to use special characters (as you do) you should encode them. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856785/characters-allowed-in-a-url, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575440/url-encoding-using-c-sharp, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44920875/url-encode-and-decode-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the action header "...abbreviation/{shortform}" you need a MVC style Url with route valulues. This Url is very sensitive to a special characters. You can try to encode/decode the special characters, but it is not always succesfull and sometimes it is not possible. It is much easier to use a query string as a part of URL. You can achieve it by changing  your action header to this

```
[Route("~/api/emoticon/abbreviation")]
 public string Abbreviation(string ShortForm)
```

and after this you can use this url

```
localhost/api/emoticon/abbreviation?shortForm=(~.~)
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! Could you elaborate on why the url must have a ? after abbreviation?