# How can I apply HTML decoding in an Azure API Management (C#) policy expression?

Tags: c#, azure-api-management

I have payload in a HTTP POST body where I need to apply HTML decoding on specific fields before forwarding to the backend. How can I achieve this in API Management policy expressions where System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode seems not to be available [- also see feedback forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/19043419-support-urlencoding-for-the-c-implementation)?

Trying to use a self-made version fails, because policy editor translates `&auml;` to `ä`:

```
<set-body>@{
    string HtmlDecode(string input) => input.Replace("&auml;","ä");
    var body = context.Request.Body.As<JObject>(true);
    body["field1"] = HtmlDecode(body["field1"].ToString());
    return body.ToString();
}</set-body>
```

Comment: Do you have access to the `System.Net.WebUtility` namespace? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35437491/webutility-htmldecode-replacement-in-net-core

Comment: unfortunately no, when trying a System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode() I get: Usage of type 'System.Net.WebUtility' is not supported within expressions

Comment: This functionality looks to be missing indeed. You could try escaping the ampersand `.Replace("\u0026auml;","ä")` but you are going to have to do a lot of find/replace.

Comment: Thanks @dana, I'll try this as a workaround until a final solution comes into place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not my preferred and intended solution but with help of @Dana and Maxim Kim (API Management team) a workaround:

```
<set-body>@{
    Dictionary<string,string> decoderPairs = new Dictionary<string,string>() 
    {
        {"&amp;auml;","ä"},
        {"&amp;ouml;","ö"},
        {"&amp;uuml;","ü"},
        {"&amp;Auml;","Ä"},
        {"&amp;Ouml;","Ö"},
        {"&amp;Uuml;","Ü"},
        {"&amp;szlig;","ß"},
        {"&amp;amp;","&"}
    };                
    string HtmlDecode(string input) { foreach(var p in decoderPairs) { input = input.Replace(p.Key,p.Value); } return input; }
    var body = context.Request.Body.As<JObject>(true);
    body["field1"] = HtmlDecode((body["field1"] ?? "").ToString());
    return body.ToString();
}</set-body>
```

### **EDIT**

since this [release](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-api-management-update-oct-24/) the proper solution is available

```
<set-body>@{
    var body = context.Request.Body.As<JObject>(true);
    body["field1"] = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode((body["field1"] ?? "").ToString());
    return body.ToString();
}</set-body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Now you don't even have to use c# to decode your HTML escaped string. Just use the System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode directly:

```
<set-body>@(System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(escaped_string))</set-body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since API Management policy expressions support XDocument, you can use this to decode most blocks of html/xml data:

`string DecodeHtml(string value) { if (value == null) return null; return XDocument.Parse($"<root>{value}</root>").Root.Value; }`