# Getting right encoding from HTTPContext

Tags: c#, .net, seo, httpcontext

I am trying to build site titles generated dynamically from HTTPContext , but I saw that I have problems when url contains special characters like `ß` which results in titles having wrong characters for instance `fußball` translates into `fu%C3%9Fball`. Right now I store my title in array like that:

```
string[] customSEOTitle = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath
   .Split('/')
   .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
   .Distinct()
   .Select(s => CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(s))
   .ToArray();
```

The thing is that AbsolutePath returns `fu%C3%9Fball` when the url is actually `fußball`. I saw that `RawUrl` gets right characters , but it does take query string also which I don't want.Is there any generic and straightforward way to do this or I have to write extension method striping query string?

Comment: Try use  HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might be looking are UrlEncode and UrlDecode methods.

[MSDN | HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt(v=vs.110).aspx)

Not sure which .NET version you use, see elaborate discussion here.

[Replacement for System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode/UrlDecode ASP.NET 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32434401/replacement-for-system-web-httputility-urlencode-urldecode-asp-net-5)

Comment: Thanks, I don't know what I missed earlier .. cause I am 100% sure that I saw that method.